# How to get object sender in class static method

Tags: c#, asp.net

It's my code snipper to print message

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Default2()
    {
        DebugManage.ShowMessage(this, "hello");
    }
}

public class DebugManager
{
    static public void ShowMessage(System.Web.UI.Page handle, string message)
    {
        string script = "alert(\"MESSAGE!\");".Replace("MESSAGE", message);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(handle, handle.GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change the code familiar with below

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Default2()
    {
        DebugManage.ShowMessage("hello");
        // no need to specify windows handle
    }
}

public class DebugManager
{
    // how to get object sender automaic
    static public void ShowMessage(object sender, string message)
    {
        string script = "alert(\"MESSAGE!\");".Replace("MESSAGE", message);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(handle, handle.GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
    }
}
```

I know if new the the class like

```
DebugManager mgr = new DebugManager(handle)
```

can solve this problem. I just curious, is it possible to do this by static method.

Comment: Should your `DebugManager` guess from which component it was called? That´s of course not possible, you have to provie this information, unless you have some static reference to your webpage.

Comment: `"alert(\"MESSAGE!\");".Replace("MESSAGE", message);`? Why are you replacing instead of using proper string formatting?

Comment: cause I don't know how to set string formatting.   

string script = "alert(\" + message + "!\");"; 

is not working

Comment: OK, I got it. string script = "alert(\"" + message + "\");"; is working

Comment: You could create your own HttpModule, in which you would check whenever the request is for page and then attach the call to DebugManager to whatever part of request execution pipeline event you want.

Comment: how to do pipeline?

Comment: @KenChu No need to do pipeline, it's build in asp.net and it's executed for all incoming request. The point is that HttpModules are ways to influence it, you can attach own logic for when request is started etc, whenever the request handler is page, then you can attach own logic for page's events (onload etc.). I suggest you check [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx). This might seem like an overkill for what you are trying to do, but it will get the job done. As for your original question, as others have already said, it's not possible the way you want it.

Comment: You can use string interpolation for the local variable `script`, as in `var script = $"alert(\"{message}!\");";`. Note the `$` and the `{` and `}`.

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but you can declare the method as `static public void ShowMessage(string message, [CallerMemberName] string sender = null) { … }`. To use the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` you need a `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;` directive. Then you can omit the argument corresponding to the parameter with the attribute `[CallerMemberName]` when you call the method, as in `DebugManage.ShowMessage("hello");`. Because of the attribute, some magic will mean the string `sender` will contain the name of the caller, like `".ctor"` for an instance constructor.

Comment: CallerMemberName return method name. not class name.